# print multiline statement in a single line

Tags: python, printing, multiline

I have a huge number that looks like this (a simplified version of the original):

```
NUM = """
      74
      89
      90
      """
```

How can I print it in a way that it would be a single line number without spaces in between? Something like this:

```
748990
```

I tried with:

```
num = NUM.replace('\n', '').strip()
print(num)
```

But I got it like:

```
74    89    90
```

I would like to avoid the option of writing quotes and \ simbols in all lines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NUM.replace('\n', '').strip()

The above will not work are strip trim from the front and end, not in middle.

you can use `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[ \n]', '', NUM)
'748990'
```

Using `re.findall`:

```
>>> "".join(re.findall("\d", NUM))
'748990'
```

you can do like this also

```
>>> NUM.replace("\n", '').replace(' ', '')
'748990'
```

Using `filter` and `str.isdigit`:

Python 3.x

```
>>> "".join(filter(str.isdigit, NUM))
'748990'
```

Python 2.x

```
>>> filter(str.isdigit, NUM)
'748990'
```

Comment: `re` could be a bit overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can get each line with `split()` and them `join()` them:

```
>>> ''.join(NUM.split())
'748990'
```